# enable/disable ntp service on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ntp, ntpd, ntpdate

Our application runs on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise. On this server, we have both `ntpdate` and `ntp`.

How to enable and disable the NTP service on-demand? I tried

```
# sudo update-rc.d -f ntp remove/default
```

and

```
# sudo update-rc.d ntp enable/disable
```

commands, but when I reboot server the `ntp` service starts running!

I suspect `ntpdate` is starting `ntp` service on reboot. I removed `ntpdate` package from one of my experimental server, then `ntp` didn't start on reboot after issuing:

```
# update-rc.d ntp disable
```

Is there a way to control this? or is there way to permanently disable `ntpdate`?

Comment: I see ntpdate is starting ntp service on interface up. once I put `exit 0` on top of the script `/etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate` everything is working as intended.

Comment: I have the exact sae behaviour. Did you manage to ofind othe solution. I needed to remove the ntp to get it not boot up :D

Answer (score 3):

Coming in a couple years late, but hopefully it will help.

This will fix the unexpected interaction between ntpdate & ntp:

```
rm -f /etc/network/if-up.d/ntpdate
```

Then when you do a "update-rc.d ntp disable", ntp won't start on reboot.

Answer (score 1):

The [ntpdate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ntpdate.8.html) command is a program that can be used to set the system time one off. There is nothing to enable or disable with ntpdate and nor does it control the ntp service.

The ntp service controls the action of the [ntpd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/ntpd.8.html) daemon. This can be disabled with the command

```
update-rc.d ntp disable
```

and then you can start and stop it using the service command

```
service ntp start
service ntp stop
```

On an Ubuntu system I have to hand with both ntp and ntpdate installed, this all works as expected. Disabling the ntp service and rebooting, the service remains off.

Comment: I followed the same steps but not working for me!  I also tried by freshly installing ntpdate and ntp but same result- ntp is stating on reboot. Is there a way to find in logs who is staring ntp? I see all the ntp rc files are in kill mode after issuing `update-rc.d ntp disable` command!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution from [Disable Time Synchronization on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/a/103241):

> To disable ntpdate on an Ubuntu system without removing it you could simply update `/etc/default/ntpdate` and add the word `exit` as the first line or change the `NTPSERVERS` variable to be empty.

Comment: Thanks japao. I tried this also but no use. I even set usentpconf option to NO. Nothing is helping me.